# Javascript variable not setting properly?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am making an HTML5 canvas racing game and I want to save the best scores in cookies, and then recover them. Here is my code:

```
var json_str = getCookie('best');
if(!(json_str == "")){
    console.log(JSON.parse(json_str));
    var bests = JSON.parse(json_str);
    console.log(bests);
}else{
    var bests = [[[99999999,""],[99999999,""],[99999999,""],[99999999,""],[9999999,""],[9999999,""]],[[99999999,""],[99999999,""],[99999999,""],[99999999,""],[9999999,""],[9999999,""]]];
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when the 'best' cookie isn't my only cookie, the first console.log returns the correct array. However the second console.log returns an array that is half right and half wrong. Therefore, I think for some reason the bests variable isn't setting properly only when I have more than one cookie.

I have tried changing the name of the variable but then this call `best[activeTrack][mactive][1]` gives the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`. I can send other code to help you out, thanks for helping.

Comment: Sounds like you need to fix your `getCookie` function. You might find it easier to use `localStorage` though.

Comment: Highlighted `I can send other code to help you out`

Comment: I don't think that's the problem as the JSON.parse works just fine and its value is accurate. I will look into localStorage.